# Permission denied when importing binascii

Tags: python-2.7

I am installed CPython 2.7 in AIX, server level is 7.2.0.0. Everything is Ok when using the Python CLI as the root user, yet a normal user gets a `Permission denied`-error when importing `binascii`:

```
>>> import binascii
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: Permission denied
```

I have checked the permissions for the `binascii` modules:

```
/opt/freeware/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so
/opt/freeware/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so
```

they are 755 permission, same as the other normal server.

```
$ ls -l /opt/freeware/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so

-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     system        30668 Feb 20 2017  /opt/freeware/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so

$ ls -l /opt/freeware/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so

-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     system        33280 Feb 20 2017  /opt/freeware/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Use programs `truss` and `ldd` to debug.

Comment: Hi Lorinczy, thanks for your suggestion, will try it. there have one SA change the directory file permission, now not sure which file have the wrong permission.